# How to show week list for the specific date and week start from sunday

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have week list dates logic from the specific date which returns following results.

```
12/05/2016 Monday 
12/06/2016 Tuesday 
12/07/2016 Wednesday 
12/08/2016 Thursday 
12/09/2016 Friday 
12/10/2016 Saturday 
12/11/2016 Sunday
```

Logic:

```
// set current date
$date = '12/08/2016';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
$ts = strtotime($date);
// calculate the number of days since Monday
$dow = date('w', $ts);
$offset = $dow - 1;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Monday
$ts = $ts - $offset*86400;
// loop from Monday till Sunday 
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++, $ts += 86400){
    print date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Currently getting days from `Monday` to `Sunday` but don't know how to start a week from Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

Replace "1" with "0".

```
$offset = $dow - 0;
```

Comment: I have replaced with `0` and week displayed with `Sunday` and what about others? Like Tuesday?

Comment: see format "w". "0" means Sunday, "1" means Monday. Tuesday is "2".